# how to use the promise '.then' component of transaction in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, promise

I'm using firebase and need to increment a counter so `transaction` seems to be the most appropriate contender. i understand that transaction uses a promise, however i am unclear (and the manuals dont have examples) on how to use the `.then` component of the promise.

At the moment in prototyping, i can 'slow it down' by using an alert like this:

```
var oldPosScore = firebase.database().ref('/data/n:'+stateNum[plus] + '/score/');
        oldPosScore.transaction (function(increment1) {
            alert ('POSITIVE statement number: ' + stateNum[plus] );            
            return ((increment1 || 0)*1 + 1);
        });
```

What syntax do i use to set this up?  where/how does the `.then` work in this use-case?

**EDIT** (added data structure):
Instead of firebase push keys i am using numbers so i can randomly select them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you can use transaction promise like below,

```
var oldPosScore = firebase.database().ref('/data/n:'+stateNum[plus]);

    oldPosScore.child('score').transaction (function(increment1) {  
        return ((increment1 || 0)*1 + 1);
    }).then(function(){
      alert("transaction successfull");
}).catch(function(err){
   alert(err);
});
```

see my [Js Fiddle Sample for Transaction "then" Promise](https://jsfiddle.net/o7r2o0v9/8/)

I have edited my Js fiddle. See this whether it works for you or not?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i notice you have left my original alert (used to slow it down) in place. i tried your suggestion but it doesnt work if i remove the alert ... i.e. it still doesn't write to the firebase database. should the `return` be after the `.then`?

Comment: can you show me your data structure i.e your ref ref('/data/n:'+stateNum[plus] + '/score/');. I can't understand this ref why you're using 'data/n:' like this.

Comment: edited question now shows data structure and reason for it :)

Comment: Hi, transaction "return" will update the processed value to the firebase database once it's done, then promise will be called. So "return" should be first and then "then" call works.

Comment: Hi. i changed the firebase ref to the way you have structured it in the jsFiddle: `var fbRef1 = firebase.database().ref('/data/n:'+stateNum[plus]);` and then `fbRef1.child('score').transaction (function(increment1)` and it's working. Not sure why it would work with `child` and not with the previous ref. arrangement. ideas?

Comment: If it's working please upvote the answer. I will also google about why it's not working with your previous ref and I will update soon.

Comment: yes will do. can you pls change your answer to remove the `alerts` so it answers my question. thanks

Comment: I can't understand do you want me to remove this "alert ('POSITIVE statement number: ' + stateNum[plus] );   " from the answer is it so?

Comment: yes. my question needed to work without alerts. thanks

Comment: I have deleted the alert. If I provided what you need, please upvote the answer.